# Kodak EasyShare M590 plugging into Ubuntu

Tags: mount, camera, 7.10

I've got a Kodak EasyShare M590 that I plug into my Ubuntu Computer. How do I get it to mount the card to copy the photos over to the computer?

This is a slightly old Ubuntu, version 7.10.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering the question myself, the camera has a menu to switch from Kodak software to "Other applications (Apple Iphoto, etc)" which turn the device into mass storage mode.